# Troubleshooting too long SSL connection

Tags: ssl, connection

Since a few days, I'm sometimes facing a too long SSL connection when connecting to my website.

[SSL connection too long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inxg7.png)

But I can't figure out the origin of that problem.

When everything is OK,

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
```

returns me a response in less than 50 milliseconds. But when I'm facing the slowness connection, this command returns me a response in 5-10 seconds.

---

So I decided to monitor my webserver with a few metrics such as memory, CPU, number of Apache opened files, http sessions but none of them seem to be correlated to the problem.

When I browse my website in HTTP instead of HTTPS, I don't have the problem.

In Security panel of Chrome dev tools, it tells me that the certificate is valid.

Would you please have an idea to help me find the origin of the problem ?

---

**Update #1 :**

Here is my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf :

`SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512`

And 
`cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`
returns me about 800.

Answer (score 1):

If the delay is indeed in negotiating the SSL session you might want to check the if the [`SSLRandomSeed`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrandomseed) directive points to `/dev/random`. /dev/random is quite secure but it is also blocking when your system has insufficient entropy (check with `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`).

Changing `SSLRandomSeed` to use `/dev/urandom` (which never blocks) is usually the solution for that problem.

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn but I think it's already configured like that. (cf **Update #1**)